# Google Maps Pin in my Android application

Tags: java, android

I need to display user inserted pins on the map that i will have in my application.
This pin needs to be visible to all the users using the app.
I have no clue how to implement this.
Can i get some help please?

Comment: Simply, access user location and save it to your server database and use that locations to show on map or anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Pins in Google Maps are called Markers and they are pretty simple to create.

Following what is documented from the Google Maps API [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker), you just use the addMarker() method to create a marker and can customize the options of where it should be placed and the title to show when it is clicked on

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Hello world"));
}
```